# Scriptaculous Fade Appear on Mouseover issue

Tags: mouseover, scriptaculous

i'm trying to make a rollover of images on a link.
I'm trusting on prototype and scriptaculous.

Check this fiddle: [Rollover test](http://jsfiddle.net/rmalesani/yLLRw/3/)
All it's working well except for a strange behavious when you scroll the mouse over the link very very quick or many times.

In that case, the images and link disappears..
This is caused by the 'display:none' status brought by the scriptaculous effects, blocked I mean..

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could tyr the afterFinish function like this

```
Event.observe($('back1'), 'mouseover', function() {        
    new Effect.Fade('back1', { duration: 0.3,afterFinish:function () {   
      new Effect.Appear('back2', { duration: 0.3 });
      }
    });    

    });     
Event.observe($('back2'), 'mouseout', function() {        
    new Effect.Fade('back2', { duration: 0.3 ,afterFinish:function () { 
      new Effect.Appear('back1', { duration: 0.3 });
      }
    });    

    });
```

Comment: I tried your solution Webjunkie, it works without make everything disappear, but it's not the effect I wanted to achieve. AfterFinish function make images swap slowly with a 'blank' background between, I want them swap immediately (with fade effect) instead. Thanks anyway